# UITableViewController not loading custom cells using xib file

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableViewController and want to populate it with custom cells. The cell I have created has it's own class and xib file, away from the main storyboard.

In the xib file, I have 'VisitCell' as the identifier.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VisitCell", for: indexPath) as! VisitCell

    let visit : BookingVisitItem = bookingDayItem.getVisitItems()[indexPath.row]

    cell.locationLabel?.text = visit.getVenueName()
    cell.timeLabel?.text = visit.getVisitTime()
    cell.typeLabel?.text = visit.getVisitType()

    return cell
}
```

If I run the code like this, it seems to crash. Maybe it can't find the custom cell?

However, if I add the following to viewDidLoad()

```
tableView.register(VisitCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "VisitCell")
```

At this stage, it doesn't crash but the table view appears to be empty.

Any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: Have you implement other delegates like ` override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        //return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       // return 3
    }` It would have been better if you had also kept the error log along with how you implemented table view delegates.

Comment: @sark9012 please also mention crash.I may be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register your nib cell in `viewDidLoad()`-:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        yourTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "yourcell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellOne")
    }
```

Comment: That's sorted it. From things I had read, nothing was using a custom xib away from the storyboard so I assumed there was something to do with that, hence mentioning it in the question. Thanks a lot!